# What does setting the 'contamination' parameter to 'auto' in Sklearn Outlier Detection methods do?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, outliers, anomaly-detection

I have a dataset where I need to be able to control to what extent the Outlier Detection Model (Isolation Forest, Elliptic Envelope, OneClassSVM...) considers a given point an outlier or not (something similar to the Z-score or IQR-score). This means that I do not want to specify in advance the percentage of outlier points in my dataset, better known as the `contamination` parameter, but I want this percentage to depend on how "picky" I want my model to be. Is this the same as setting the parameter `contamination` to 'auto'?

Here's what the Sci-kit Learn package says about this:
"if ‘auto’, the threshold is determined as in the original paper".

Which original paper does this refer to? And does setting the `contamination` parameter to 'auto' solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking at the paper without much success, but looking at the code gave me the answer. Note this part of the implementation:

```
    if self.contamination == "auto":
        # 0.5 plays a special role as described in the original paper.
        # we take the opposite as we consider the opposite of their score.
        self.offset_ = -0.5
        return self

    # else, define offset_ wrt contamination parameter
    self.offset_ = np.percentile(self.score_samples(X),
                                 100. * self.contamination)
```

You can check the full implementation [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/fd237278e895b42abe8d8d09105cbb82dc2cbba7/sklearn/ensemble/_iforest.py#L228).

When you set the `contamination='auto'` the `offset_` value, which impacts in the prediction of your model, is set to `-0.5`, while if you use a `float` value in the `contamination` parameter the offset value will vary to achieve the percentage of contamination that you previously passed. So the model will determine the percentage of contamination in your data based on this decision.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Indeed that is what I ended up finding as well. However, doesn't the offset_ value of -0.5 also technically correspond to a given percentage of contamination too? In this case, setting the contamination parameter to 'auto' does not necessarily help me

Comment: Yes, -0.5 corresponds to a percentage, but because it's a fixed value it does not impact the prediction, hence the decision if a sample is or not an outlier is purely defined by the algorithm.

Comment: So this means that the contamination parameter doesn't end up affecting our prediction? If so it's a good sign. In this case, the 'extent' to which a point is an outlier or an inlier can be defined by the user, right? Since all what the decision function now does is give an anomaly score, if I understood well

Comment: @lalfab oh, I updated question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/515654/how-can-we-introduce-an-anomaly-class-as-a-positive-class-to-sklearn-isolationfo)

Answer (score 1):

The contamination rate used in the paper was 10% https://cs.nju.edu.cn/zhouzh/zhouzh.files/publication/icdm08b.pdf
"In our experiments,
the basic setting for Mulcross is as following: contamination ratio = 10% (number of anomalies over the total number of points),In our experiments,
the basic setting for Mulcross is as following: contamination ratio = 10% (number of anomalies over the total number of points),"